# Where to find walla/ ambiences suitable for historical drama?

Tags: library, samples, walla

I'm working on a radio drama set in ancient Rome and I'm having trouble finding walla/ ambience/ room tones that are inconspicuous.

Most of the audio files I can get my hands on are only really suitable for modern/ 20th century use. There's always a detectable car sound or a phone ring or a noticeably American voice in the crowd sounds, or it sounds like a mall or stadium rather than an open space.

Can anyone suggest any sources? I'm not after genuine accuracy, just something that's not obviously modern/ urban sounding. There must be something pitched at all the Game of Thrones knockoffs out there now.

I'm relying on sample libraries for this and can't really record anything myself If there was some kind of Roman re-enactment happening locally that would be awesome but probably unlikely.

Thanks.